# Browser Extension to show how your session is being shared

Tags: web-browser, privacy, browser-extensions

A while back I came across a browser extension (was available for Firefox and Chrome, maybe others) that showed you through a graphical 'node' interface how your browser session was shared with so many other servers and web services.

Unfortuneatly I have forgotten its names, and because I don't know what the correct technical terminology is, I can't find it through searching Google.

If you know of that extension, can you please share. It was very useful, because it showed which websites were particularly bad, they shared the session with like 20 or so other websites. I remember Fb and Amazon were shocking!

Thanks

Comment: [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com) shows you what tracking services are present on a given website - not a 'node' interface though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension is called [Collusion](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/collusion/).  It shows the cookie tracker networks.  I use it in talks to demonstrate how quickly your privacy is lost when browsing less than 5 websites.

Comment: Yess, Collusion was the one. :D I just couldn't remember its name. Thank You Callum :)